# Parsing xml files, ideas to design my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, lxml

I begun to work for a company which do not have enough time to practice code review. As a beginner programmer I would like to improve my skills on real working cases.
I have been asked to facilitate translations on  "tableau workbook" files (those are just XML files) by replacing french text with English one.

I work in 4 steps (so I wrote 4 files which can be run independently):

1. Load textual field from ".twb" file to dump them in database
2. Load textual field from database and write them in an excel worksheet to be translated by the "language technical team"
3. Dump the translated field in Database
4. Write a new ".twb" file based on the field which have been translated.

Most of my work lay on retrieving interesting field from .twb file (XML file). So I wrote a helper file which have function to retrieve/get the interesting nodes and other function that update nodes in the XML file (the XML file can be viewed as a tree with nodes). Here is an extract of my helper file to give you an idea of what I try to accomplish.

I suppose that my design is awful and would be pleased if you could give me some advice (OO design, etc...) or any recommendation (books, ...) to help me improve my design skill.

```
from lxml import etree
import os
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import namedtuple
from ast import literal_eval
import re

####### Variable globales ######
textual_node = namedtuple('textual_node', ['id', 'label', 'type'])
stop_words = ['<', '>', 'Æ', '', '\n', ':', '()']


####### Parsing xml #######
def get_root_tree(file_source):
    tree = etree.parse(file_source)
    root = tree.getroot()
    return tree, root

####### Utilities #########
def get_parent(node,depth):
    """ Retrieve ancestor node """
    ancestor_node = node
    for i in range(depth):
        ancestor_node=ancestor_node.getparent()
    return ancestor_node

def get_brute_path(root,tree,xpath):
    brute_paths = []
    paths = []
    for node in root.xpath(xpath):
        path = tree.getpath(node)
        brute_path = clean_path(path)
        if not (brute_path  in brute_paths):
            paths.append(path)
            brute_paths.append(brute_path)
    return brute_paths,paths

def clean_path(path):
    split_path = [elt.split('[')[0] for elt in path.split('/')]
    brute_path = '/'.join(split_path)
    return brute_path

def get_ws_name(root, tree):
    """ Mapping between worksheet's name and worksheet's number in the xml file"""
    d_wsname = {}
    d_inv_wsname = {}
    for node in root.xpath('worksheets/worksheet[@name]'):
        ws_id = tree.getpath(node).split('/')[-1]
        ws_name = node.get('name')
        d_wsname[ws_id] = ws_name
        d_inv_wsname[ws_name] = ws_id
    return d_wsname, d_inv_wsname

####### Get nodes of interest #########
def get_alias(root):
    """ Get the aliases nodes """
    s_alias = set()
    xpath = "/workbook/datasources/datasource/column/aliases/alias"
    for node in root.xpath(xpath):
            ds_node = get_parent(node,3)
            ds_id = ds_node.attrib['name']
            col_node = get_parent(node,2)
            col_id = col_node.attrib['name']
            alias_id = node.attrib['key']
            node_id = (ds_id,col_id,alias_id)
            node_text = node.attrib['value']
            node_type = 'alias'
            alias_node = textual_node(node_id, node_text, node_type)
            s_alias.add(alias_node)
    return s_alias

def get_member(root):
    """ Get the member nodes"""
    s_member = set()
    xpath = "/workbook/datasources/datasource/column/members/member[@alias]"
    for node in root.xpath(xpath):
        ds_node = get_parent(node,3)
        ds_id = ds_node.attrib['name']
        col_node = get_parent(node, 2)
        col_id = col_node.attrib['name']
        member_id = node.attrib['value']
        node_id = (ds_id, col_id, member_id)
        node_text = node.attrib['alias']
        node_type = 'member'
        member_node =  textual_node(node_id, node_text, node_type)
        s_member.add(member_node)
    return s_member

def get_title_format(tree,root):
    """ Get the title text"""
    s = set()
    xpath = '//format[@attr="title"][@value]'
    for node in root.xpath(xpath):
        ws_id = get_parent(node, 4).attrib['name']
        fm_id = node.attrib['field']
        node_id = (ws_id, fm_id)
        node_text = node.get('value')
        node_type = 'title_'+node.tag
        title_format_node = textual_node(node_id, node_text, node_type)
        s.add(title_format_node)
    return s





def get_formatted_format(tree,root):
    """ Get the formatted text """
    raw = r"(?P<type>^.)(?:\"(?P<prefix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1}(?P<format>[^\"]*)(?:\"(?P<suffix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1};(?P<negformat>.)(?:\"(?P=prefix)\"){0,1}(?P=format)(?:\"(?P=suffix)\"){0,1}"
    pattern = re.compile(raw)
    s_format = set()
    xpath = '//format[@attr="text-format"]' # xpath = "/workbook/worksheets//table/style/style-rule/format[@field][@attr='text-format']"
    for node in root.xpath(xpath):
        fm_text = node.attrib['value']
        matches = pattern.search(fm_text)
        if matches:
            ws_id = get_parent(node,4).attrib['name']
            fm_id = node.attrib['field']
            node_id = (ws_id,fm_id)
            match_dic = matches.groupdict()
            node_prefix,node_suffix = match_dic['prefix'], match_dic['suffix']
            if node_prefix:
                if node_prefix.strip()!='€':
                    node_type = "{}_prefix".format(node.tag)
                    format_prefix_node = textual_node(node_id, node_prefix, node_type)
                    s_format.add(format_prefix_node)
            if node_suffix:
                if node_suffix.strip() != '€':
                    node_type = "{}_suffix".format(node.tag)
                    format_suffix_node = textual_node(node_id, node_suffix, node_type)
                    s_format.add(format_suffix_node)
    return s_format

def get_caption(root):
    """ Get the column names (original and calculated ones)"""
    s_caption = set()
    for node in root.xpath('/workbook/datasources/datasource/column[@caption]'):
        node_id = node.get('name')
        node_text = node.get('caption')
        node_type = node.tag
        caption_node = textual_node(node_id, node_text, node_type)
        s_caption.add(caption_node)
    return s_caption


def get_tooltip_label(root, tree, d_wsname):
    """" Get the tooltip and label """
    s_tooltip_label = set()
    nodes_type = ['customized-tooltip','customized-label']
    for node_type in nodes_type:
        ancestor_path = '//worksheets/*/table/panes/pane/{node_type}/formatted-text/run/ancestor::pane'.format(node_type=node_type)
        for ancestor in root.xpath(ancestor_path):
            try:
                pane_id = ancestor.attrib["id"]
            except:
                pane_id=''
            finally:
                run_path="{node_type}/formatted-text/run".format(node_type=node_type)
                for node in ancestor.xpath(run_path):
                    if not any(substring == node.text.strip() for substring in stop_words):  # 'Æ', '<['
                        ws_id = tree.getpath(node).split('/')[3]
                        ws_name = d_wsname[ws_id]
                        run_index = tree.getpath(node)[-2:-1]
                        node_id = (ws_name,pane_id,run_index)
                        node_text = node.text
                        node_type = tree.getpath(node).split('/')[-3]
                        tooltip_label_node = textual_node(node_id, node_text, node_type)
                        s_tooltip_label.add(tooltip_label_node)
    return s_tooltip_label

def get_zone(root,tree):
    """ Get the textual zones """
    s_zone = set()
    xpath_run = "/workbook/dashboards/dashboard/zones//zone/formatted-text/run"
    for run_node in root.xpath(xpath_run):
        if not any(substring == run_node.text.strip() for substring in stop_words):
            previous_zone_node = get_parent(run_node,2)
            pane_id = previous_zone_node.attrib['id']
            run_index = tree.getpath(run_node)[-2:-1]
            node_id = (pane_id,run_index)
            node_text = run_node.text
            node_type =  tree.getpath(run_node).split('/')[-3].split('[')[0]
            zone_node = textual_node(node_id,node_text,node_type)
            s_zone.add(zone_node)
    return s_zone

def get_node_info(tree,node):
    info = " tree.getpath(node): {path} \n node.items(): {attr} \n node.text: {text}".format(path=tree.getpath(node),attr=node.items(),text=node.text)
    print(info)

def get_ancestor_by_name(root,tree,node,namefield):
    path = tree.getpath(node)
    brute_path = clean_path(path)
    hier = brute_path.split('/')[1:]
    for i,elt in enumerate(hier):
        if namefield==elt:
            return get_parent(node,len(hier)-i-1)
    return False

############### Update Nodes #############################
def update_wblocal(root,lang):
    dic_lang = {'FR':'fr_FR','EN':'en_GB','ES':'es_ES'}
    root.attrib['locale'] = dic_lang[lang]
    return root

def update_nodes(df, root):
    root_trad = deepcopy(root)
    tree_trad = etree.ElementTree(root_trad)
    d_wsname, d_inv_wsname = get_ws_name(root_trad, tree_trad)
    d_func = {"customized-tooltip": update_customized_node, "customized-label": update_customized_node,
              "column": update_caption_node,"zone":update_zone_node,"alias":update_alias_node,
              "member":update_member_node,"format_prefix":update_format_node,"format_suffix":update_format_node,
              "title_format":update_title_format_node}
    d_args = {"customized-tooltip": (d_inv_wsname, root_trad, tree_trad), "customized-label": (d_inv_wsname, root_trad, tree_trad),
              "column": (root_trad, tree_trad) ,"zone":(root_trad, tree_trad),"alias":(root_trad,tree_trad),
              "member":(root_trad,tree_trad),"format_suffix":(root_trad,tree_trad),"format_prefix":(root_trad,tree_trad),
              "title_format":(root_trad,tree_trad)}
    for  index, row in df.iterrows():
        node_type = row['node_type']
        d_func[node_type](row,*d_args[node_type])
    return root_trad, tree_trad

def update_title_format_node(row,root,tree):
    """ Get the title text"""
    xpath = '//format[@attr="title"][@value]'
    brute_paths, _ = get_brute_path(root, tree, xpath)
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    ws_id, fm_id = node_id
    dic = {'worksheet': ('name', ws_id), 'format': ('field', fm_id)}
    for brute_path in brute_paths:
        nodes = iterpath(root,tree,brute_path,dic)
        for node in nodes:
            print("Avant title_format: ", node.attrib['value'])
            node.attrib['value'] = row.to_replace
            print("Après title_format:", node.attrib['value'])
    return root, tree

def update_format_node(row,root,tree):
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    raw = r"(?P<type>^.)(?:\"(?P<prefix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1}(?P<format>[^\"]*)(?:\"(?P<suffix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1};(?P<negformat>.)(?:\"(?P=prefix)\"){0,1}(?P=format)(?:\"(?P=suffix)\"){0,1}"
    pattern = re.compile(raw)
    xpath = '//format[@attr="text-format"][@field]' # xpath = "/workbook/worksheets//table/style/style-rule/format[@field][@attr='text-format']"
    brute_paths,_ = get_brute_path(root,tree,xpath)
    ws_id,fm_id = node_id
    dic = {'worksheet':('name',ws_id),'format':('field',fm_id)}
    for brute_path in brute_paths:
        nodes = iterpath(root,tree,brute_path,dic)
        for node in nodes:
            node_text = node.attrib['value']
            print("Avant format: ", node_text)
            dic = pattern.search(node_text).groupdict()
            dic_pattern = {'format_prefix':dic['prefix'],'format_suffix':dic['suffix']}
            pattern = dic_pattern[row.node_type]
            new_text = node_text.replace(pattern,row.to_replace)
            node.attrib['value'] = new_text
            print("Après format:", node.attrib['value'])
    return root,tree

def update_alias_node(row,root,tree):
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    ds_id, col_id,alias_id = node_id
    xpath = "//alias"
    brute_paths,_ = get_brute_path(root,tree,xpath)
    dic = {'datasource':('name',ds_id),'datasource-dependencies':('datasource',ds_id),\
           'column':('name',col_id),'alias':('key',alias_id)}
    for brute_path in brute_paths:
        nodes = iterpath(root,tree,brute_path,dic)
        for node in nodes:
            print("Avant alias: ", node.attrib['value'])
            node.attrib['value'] = row.to_replace
            print("Après Alias:", node.attrib['value'])
    return root,tree

def iterpath(node,tree,rightpath,dic,nodes=None):
    """ This recursive algorithm traverse the tree till the last element of the specified path
    (from top to bottom) looking if (key,value) pair of nodes match with dictionary """
    if nodes == None:
        nodes =[]
    node_tag = node.tag
    if len(rightpath.split('/'))>1:
        _, rightpath = rightpath.split("{}/".format(node_tag))
        if rightpath:
            next_tag,*_  = rightpath.split('/')
            xpath = "{}/{}".format(tree.getpath(node),next_tag)
            if node_tag in dic.keys():
                key, value = dic[node_tag]
                if node.attrib[key] != value:
                    return False
            for child_node in node.xpath(xpath):
                    iterpath(child_node, tree, rightpath, dic,nodes)
    else: #last node of the original specified path (fisrt call to the function)
        key, key_id = dic[node_tag]
        try:
            if node.attrib[key] == key_id:
                nodes.append(node)
        except KeyError:
            print("KeyError:",node.items())
    return nodes


def update_caption_node(row, root_trad, tree_trad):
    node_id = row['node_id']
    xpath_request = '//*[@name="{name}"][@caption]'.format(name=node_id)
    for node in root_trad.xpath(xpath_request):
        try:
            print("Avant caption:", node.get('caption'))
            node.attrib["caption"] = row[-1]
            print("Après caption:", node.get('caption'))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception",e)
    return root_trad, tree_trad

def update_customized_node(row, d_inv_wsname, root_trad, tree_trad):
    """ Se sert de la dernière colonne du dataframe, comme colonne de remplacement (à améliorer)"""
    node_type = row['node_type']
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    wsname = node_id[0]
    pane_id = node_id[1]
    run_index = node_id[2]
    ws = d_inv_wsname[wsname]
    if pane_id:
        xpath_pane = '//worksheets/{worksheet}/table/panes/pane[@id={pane_id}]'.format(worksheet=ws,pane_id=pane_id)
    else:
        xpath_pane = '//worksheets/{worksheet}/table/panes/pane'.format(worksheet=ws)
    if run_index != 'u':
        xpath_run = '//{node_type}/formatted-text/run[{run_index}]'.format(node_type=node_type,run_index=run_index)
    elif run_index == 'u':
        xpath_run = '//{node_type}/formatted-text/run'.format(node_type=node_type)
    for run_node in root_trad.xpath(xpath_pane+xpath_run):
        try:
            print('Avant run:', run_node.text)
            run_node.text = row[-1]
            print('Après run:', run_node.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(">",repr(e))
    return root_trad, tree_trad

def update_zone_node(row, root_trad, tree_trad):
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    zone_id = node_id[0]
    run_index = node_id[1]
    if run_index != 'u':
        xpath_run = '/workbook/dashboards/dashboard/zones//zone[@id={zone_id}]/formatted-text/run[{run_index}]'.format(zone_id=zone_id,run_index=run_index)
    elif run_index == 'u':
        xpath_run = '/workbook/dashboards/dashboard/zones//zone[@id={zone_id}]/formatted-text/run'.format(zone_id=zone_id)
    for run_node in root_trad.xpath(xpath_run):
        try:
            print('Avant run:', run_node.text)
            run_node.text = row[-1]
            print('Après run:', run_node.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(">", repr(e))
    return root_trad, tree_trad

def update_member_node(row, root, tree):
    node_id = literal_eval(row['node_id'])
    ds_id, col_id,member_id = node_id
    xpath = "//member"
    brute_paths,_ = get_brute_path(root,tree,xpath)
    dic = {'datasource':('name',ds_id),'column':('name',col_id),'member':('value',member_id)}
    for brute_path in brute_paths:
        nodes = iterpath(root,tree,brute_path,dic)
        for node in nodes:
            print("Avant member: ", node.attrib['alias'])
            node.attrib['alias'] = row.to_replace
            print("Après member:", node.attrib['alias'])
    return root,tree



# Write to file

def replace_apostroph(filepath):
    filepath2 = filepath.split('.twb')[0]+'2.twb'
    with open(filepath) as fp_in:
        with open(filepath2,'w') as fp_out:
            for line in fp_in:
                fp_out.write(line.replace("'", '&apos;').replace('"', "'").replace('/>',' />'))

def rootToXml(view_name,output_dir, language_target, tree_trad):
    twb_output = '{view}_{languageTarget}.twb'.format(view=view_name, languageTarget=language_target)
    # tree_trad = etree.ElementTree(root_trad)
    filepath = os.path.join(output_dir, twb_output)
    tree_trad.write(filepath,encoding ='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
    #replace_apostroph(filepath)
    print("Writed to {filepath}".format(filepath=filepath))
```

Comment: Your question title should be reworked to [state what your code is trying to accomplish](/help/how-to-ask). This will make your question more interesting to reviewers than the current generic title.

Comment: If this is work code, you might want to check with your management on if it is ok to post due to licensing issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the title. Concerning licensing, since this work is just an extract (very partial) in order to give an idea of the current design it won't raise any problem

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion/experience and research on Python documentation, I suggest improving the following approaches:

**First**, `namedtuple` must be used with an uppercase name, like a class.

```
Textual_Node = namedtuple('Textual_Node', ['id', 'label', 'type'])
```

This helps determine the operation of creating a new data class object. [namedtuple() Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

**Second**, try to combine all related to one data functions into classes.

For example, all functions which use `root` in attrs can be combined to one, and after improvements uses self and them attr `root`. It can look like:

```
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root

    def get_caption(self):
        do_somethink_with_root(self.root)
        ...
```

**Third**, take a one-line indent for individual blocks of related code.

**Fourth**, to save information about scripts execution use [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

P.S.: *Please, try to use linters for your code. For example, it may be a `pylint` or `flake8` for making more pythonic code style and `Pydocstyle` will do more [understandable code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). As [asks Google for the Python code style](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md), use only English in the documentation lines.*